# Incorrect information from Source hitting Bot Web API

Tags: bots, botframework

I am using Microsoft BOT Builder to create BOT using C#. I have created by Web API and hosted in Azure. I have enabled Microsoft Teams channel for my BOT.

When i try to access my BOT in teams, my Web API gets web requests from a synthetic traffic and that provides an incorrect information regarding who is trying to access my BOT. My question is - is it because of Microsoft Team or the Bot Connector which sits between the channel and my BOT web API, and is there any way i can get the real user information who is accessing my BOT web api?

I access Microsoft Team chatting with my BOT from my PC in Redmond, US. But the Web API logs show that i tried to access the web api from San Jose, California. There many such incorrect information.

Comment: What it means "incorrect information"?

Comment: @EzequielJadib i have updated my post with one such incorrect information.

Comment: Are you on a VPN?

Comment: @JasonSowers no, i am not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more detailed information about your bot traffic, including breakdown of users per channel, by setting up App Insights in your Azure instance, then register your App Insights ID & Key in the bot portal at https://botframework.com in the Settings page.

For more information about configuring App Insights for Bot Framework, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-app-insights-keys